# Getting "path" is not defined Pylance Error in my Flask app

Tags: python

This is my code in **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = 'database.db'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note

    create_database(app)

    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

i tried changing my python interpreter but still getting same error

When I run main.py it throws this error 
NameError: name 'path' is not defined

also path.exists shows 
"path" is not defined Pylance

Thanks for help

Comment: So what _is_ `path`? It's not defined anywhere in the code you posted...

Comment: the problem was i didnt import path from os

Comment: finally fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i didnt import path from os

[Error Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGDgl.png)

Comment: Please do not use images to display code. Display the code in your post.